# Mac package installer installs the folder "Contents" in /Applications instead of the bundle

Tags: install, package-management, pkg, build-version

When I try to use packaging with my .app to create a Mac installer, and I run the installer, it creates me a folder named "Contents" in my /Applications folder, instead the "bundle app" as it should.

I've test with pkgbuild + productbuild:

```
pkgbuild --component "./myapp.app" --version 1 --install-location /Applications component.pkg
productbuild  --package-path "component.pkg" --distribution "./Distribution.xml" --package-path "./Temp" --resources "./Resources" --sign mycert "myapp.pkg"
```

And just with productbuild:

```
productbuild --component "./myapp.app" /Applications -s mycert myapp.pkg
```

In both cases, I run the installer, everything seems fine, but in Applications folder I see "Contents" (that is the content of the app bundle)

I've tried with "./myapp.app/" also in --component attribute, and even adding "/Applications/myapp.app" in the --install-location

Comment: Have you tried specifying the --root option with the rest of your pkgbuild options?

Comment: --root option can't be used with --component

Comment: Can you try it with the --root option instead of --component? I remember having the same issue as you with Apple's PackageMaker tool (GUI). I found out I had to check an option called "Include root in package". I was wondering if --root did this and --component didn't.

Comment: Thank you but same problem ... "Contents" folder (and not bundle .app itself) is installed in "Applications" folder

Comment: Ok. The only other suggestion, which is more of a workaround than a fix, is to try and put the app bundle in a folder and specify a path to the folder instead. For example: copy "myapp.app" to "~/Desktop/mytempfolder/" and try "pkgbuild --compontent '~/Desktop/mytempfolder'". Hopefully that will ignore the "mytempfolder" and copy its contents, which would be the app bundle.

Comment: Nop ... but nice shot ! :-)

Comment: Why do you quote `"./myapp.app"`?

Comment: I'L'I  it does not matter, same result

Answer (score 1):

Took me a few tries to get this working (the installer managed to do some really strange stuff on my first few attempts). But this seems to work reliably.

I created a temporary folder with just the application I wanted to package (leaving the app sitting elsewhere seemed to result in the aforementioned strange behaviour), then package it from there. So I created a temporary folder called "test" on my desktop and dropped the app in there on its own. The following command then reliably results in a working package on my Desktop.

```
productbuild --component ~/Desktop/test/myapp.app /Applications ~/Desktop/myapp.pkg --sign "my certificate identity name"
```

Something that is helpful when testing is to run `sudo opensnoop | grep installd` in a Terminal at the same time. It generates a lot of output but you should be able to see the application bundle being created in something like `/var/folders/zz/GIBBERISH/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/GIBBERISH.activeSandbox/Root/` and then copied to its final destination.

Note: I'm not certain why you are using `-s` in the second example `productbuild` command you gave in your question. There are three options arguments to productbuild that start with "s" (synthesis, scripts and sign) and the man page doesn't mention using the shorter "-s" for any of them. Perhaps this is the problem. Of course it could just be a typo. :)

Comment: Nice idea ! but it's strange ... now I don't see any changes in Application ... nothing is installed, no changes ... and the installer says "the applications has been installed" with the green check at the end ... weird !

Comment: @FlamingMoe I've added a bit about opensnoop to the answer. That should help you identify where the installer is writing the application bundle if it isn't writing it to /Applications.

Comment: For me, solved just adding the name of my app at the end of install-path:

`productbuild --component ~/Desktop/test/myapp.app /Applications/myapp.app ~/Desktop/myapp.pkg --sign "my certificate identity name"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are using `--component` rather than `--root`. The docs are a bit unclear on its usage but it looks as if, like with root too, you need to specify the folder that encloses the `.app` bundle not the actual bundle path itself. I made this mistake when using `--root` and witnessed just my bundle contents getting installed into `/Applications`. The same caution is required when actually building the package using pkgbuild.

I would copy my `.app` into a `./build` folder and then:

```
pkgbuild --analyze --root ./build MyApp.plist 
pkgbuild --root ./build --component-plist MyApp.plist --identifier co.uk.MyApp --version 0 --install-location /Applications MyApp.pkg
productBuild --synthesize --package ./MyApp.pkg ./Distribution.xml
productBuild --distribution ./Distribution.xml --resources ./Resources --sign "Developer ID Installer: My Id" --package-path . ./MyApp-ver-whatever.pkg
```

Comment: The above commands don't work for me (MacOS Sierra and XCode 8.3). 
While the package is created and installed, the .app bundle isn't copied in /Applications and I cannot find it on disk